# c# how to load pictures from picture library, WP8.1 Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, windows-phone-8.1

This code takes photos with name face1.jpg, face2.jpg and so on from picture library and shows them. now the problem is that it works for first 9 pictures then it stops. but it is supposed to go through all the pictures in the gallery

```
 StorageFolder picturesFolder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
            IReadOnlyList<IStorageFile> file = await picturesFolder.GetFilesAsync(CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
            string fname;
            int picSize = 150;
            int i = 0;
            WriteableBitmap wv = new WriteableBitmap(picSize, picSize);
            WriteableBitmap mypic = new WriteableBitmap(picSize, picSize);
            if (file.Count > 0)
            {
                foreach (StorageFile f in file)
                {
                    fname = "face" + i + ".jpg";

                    if (f.Name == fname)
                    {
                        i = i + 1;
                        ImageProperties properties = await f.Properties.GetImagePropertiesAsync();
                        WriteableBitmap wb = new WriteableBitmap((int)properties.Width, (int)properties.Height);
                        wb.SetSource((await f.OpenReadAsync()).AsStream());
                        reSize(wb, wv);
                        FilterWriteableBitmap(wv, mypic);
                        img.Source = mypic;
                    }

                }
            }
```

when I try to take photo directly mean when I write `if(f.Name=="face10.jpg")` then it works but inside the loop it stops at face9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change

```
int i = 0;
```

to

```
int i = 1;
```

Assuming there are 10 files in that folder the foreach will go through 10 times but the first time it will look for face0.jpg and only ever get to face9.jpg.

Comment: the problem was  "Assuming there are 10 files in that folder the foreach will go through 10 times but the first time it will look for face0.jpg and only ever get to face9.jpg."  Thank You @Tim